# How to add an option to a bootstrap-select from the search if it does not yet exist?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/).

How can I add a new option to the `select` if I can't find it in the search menu that I get with `data-live-search="true"`, because it does not yet exist?

Comment: what u want? can you please elaborate ..

Comment: there is no option value aa in option ,and when i seacrh "aa" select show "No results matched "aa" " i click this item and it hidden , but i want to click the no result item and add option value is "aa",can i do it ?

Comment: That option will only add in that selectbox or db also?

Comment: yea i get values and texts on db so when i add option i am going to add db too

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the perfect question and how to [create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **SO is not a free** Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service _**We try to fix your code, we do not write your code**_

Comment: @RaunakGupta okay sir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow below code::

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.no-results{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(document).on('click', 'li.no-results', function () {
        var new_option = $(this).text().split('"')[1];
        $("#selectpicker")
       .append('<option>'+ new_option +'</option>')
       .selectpicker('refresh');
       //You can also call AJAX here to add the value in DB
    });
});
```

Please change these code as you want.
Working Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ktmv1vxh/1/

Comment: There are two issues ,
The one of is the new_option undefinded.
The another of one is  i have 4 this item . I need tell which is which

Comment: @MuhammedAlmaz please check my jsfiddle workable link. For AJAX part you have to google it or have post a new question.

Comment: How can i show the added option selected ? I am using the multiple selectpicker  in same page so i want to get the id of select  on  "$(document).on('click', 'li.no-results', function () {})"

Answer (score 0):

Am posting this improved answer hope it helps some one's else
use Bootstrap select as normal just add the following

CSS

```
.comboxme .dropdown-menu .no-results {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .comboxme .dropdown-menu {
        top: unset !important;
        bottom: unset !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        border: 0 !important;
    }
    .comboxme .bs-searchbox {
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        border: 0 !important;
    }
    .comboxme .btn {
        background-color: white;
        color: blue;
    }
    .comboxme .bs-caret {
        color: white;
    }
```

javascript

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    selectOnTab: true,
    size: 6
});

$(function () {
    $(".bs-searchbox input").blur(function () {
        var numberOfActiveItems = $(this).closest(".dropdown-menu").find("li.active").length;
        if (numberOfActiveItems > 0) return;
        console.log(numberOfActiveItems);
        var selectBoxName = $(this).closest(".comboxme").find("select")[0].name;
        $("#" + selectBoxName + " option[value='-1']").remove();
        $("#" + selectBoxName)
            .append('<option value="-1" selected>' + $(this).val() + '</option>')
            .selectpicker('refresh');
        $("#" + selectBoxName + "_add").remove();
        $(this).closest("form").append('<input type="hidden" id="' + selectBoxName + '_add" name="' + selectBoxName + '_add" value="' + $(this).val() + '" />');
    });
});
```

html

```
<form>
<select data-width="280px" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker comboxme form-control" data-val="true" 
data-val-required="The Status field is required." id="Status" name="Status">
<option value="1">Colorado</option>
<option value="2">Connecticut</option>
<option value="3">Delaware</option>
<option value="4">Florida</option>
<option value="6">Georgia</option>
<option value="7">Kentucky</option>
</select>
</form>
```

example: https://github.com/codejq/comboxme